# How to pass sealed data class in xml data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

In my view model I have a method `onEvent()` which get as parameter an `Event`

Event class is a sealed class with objects and data classes:

```
sealed class Event {
    data class TextChanged(val text: String) : Event()
    object OkButtonClicked : Event() //ok with INSTANCE at the end.
}
```

now I want to call `vm.onEvent()` method with `TextChanged` as a param. And isn't working when I add: `app:onTextChanged="@{(text,start, before, count)-> vm.onEvent(Event.TextChanged(text.toString()))}"`

With OkButtonClicked I use `android:onClick="@{() -> vm.onEvent(Event.OkButtonClicked.INSTANCE)}"` and it works fine.

Of course I can call a method with String as a param but I need/want to pass Event subclass in xml. How to achieve that?

Comment: new isn't support in xml

Comment: Yes I deleted the comment, thanks!